# How to maintain History for Truncate/Load Table in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, history-tables

I have to maintain history into target table for each and every change made into source table.

[image]

Comment: Your picture and description don't match the title off your question... You want to track data changes or table structure changes?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith, I want to track the data changes in my source table. If there is an insert then new row should be inserted into my target table; If there is an update on existing record then new changes should be inserted as new record into target table as active flag = Y and old row should be marked as N

Comment: Oracle has built in auditing.feature that does this for you, just turn it on

Comment: Also, Oracle SQL developer is just the GUI tool for accessing the database. I would assume you want to track the change in the oracle database itself. Everyone will understand your question, but you really should be using the correct terms.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried associating a `Materialized View` to your table to track?

You can use the Materialized view log. All changes will be saved there: [image: materialized view]

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/materialized-views